# Altering immutable plasma store numpy object using cython and a pointer to the start address of the memory

Tags: python, numpy, cython, ray, apache-arrow-plasma

I am using `ray.put(large_2d_array)` to store a large numpy 2D boolean array and then in the worker process I take a column from this shared numpy array and pass it to a cython function and then create a flat buffer view via `cdef cnp.npy_bool view = &sliced_array[0]`. With this view, I can modify the underlying buffer (setting some indices to True).

Since plasma store objects are immutable, what are the unknown problems I might face because of doing this?

I would be glad if someone can throw some light on this.

Code template:

```
import numpy as np

# ray init code
......

large_2d_array = np.zeros((6000000000, 205), dtype=bool, order='F')
shared_array = ray.put(large_2d_array)

# Call worker via ray remote here and pass the shared_array
......
......

@ray.remote(num_cpus=1)
def worker(large_2d_array, col_idx):
    array_slice = large_2d_array[:, col_idx]
    cython_function(array_slice)


#In file: cython_func.pyx

def cython_function(cnp.ndarray[cnp.npy_bool, ndim=1, mode='c'] sliced_array):
    cdef cnp.npy_bool view = &sliced_array[0]
    cdef int i
    for i in range(100):
        view[i] = True
    return
```

P.S: No two workers gain access to the same slice at the same time. Each slice (column in this case) is accessed only once and modified/writte to only once.

**Attempted actors method**
This still does not work, I think I am not doing something wrong.

```
import ray
import numpy as np

ray.init(num_cpus=4)

@ray.remote
class test:
    def __init__(self, shape):
        self.shape = shape
        self.np_array = np.zeros(shape, dtype=bool)

    def get_col_slice(self, col_idx):
        return self.np_array[:, col_idx]

    def get_array(self):
        return self.np_array

    def write_to_slice(self, col_idx, nrows):
        self.np_array[:, col_idx] = [1] * nrows

@ray.remote
def write_to_alternate_slice(actor_handle, col_idx, nrows):
    actor_handle.write_to_slice.remote(col_idx, nrows)

shape = (10, 20)
test_actor = test.remote(shape)

for i in range(10, 2):
    write_to_alternate_slice.remote(test_actor, i, 10)

print(ray.get(test_actor.get_array.remote()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case, the sliced array will be copied to your python heap memory, and modifying the array won't be reflected to other workers who access the same object reference.

Comment: So if I want to write this 2D array to disk from the child processes after the modifications, they won't be reflected, right? Is there a way to make ray allow modifying the shared arrays? I have created a request in ray as well: https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/15604

Comment: In Ray, distributed Ray objects (Objects pointed by ObjectRef classes) are immutable, so it is not supported. If you'd like to do this, we recommend to use actors. (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67457237/share-object-between-actors-in-ray/67515282?noredirect=1#comment119383236_67515282). Allowing to modify shared array by multiple workers is very tricky because you need to manage locks among processes, which makes things really complex.

Comment: I have attempted an actor based example like in the docs but doesn't seem to work. Maybe I am doing something not correct, can you please check. I have edited the above question with attempted section

Comment: I followed the docs example: https://docs.ray.io/en/master/actors.html

Comment: You should wait until `write_to_alternate_slice` is done. So before you ray.get on the actor method, call `ray.get([write_to_alternate_slice.remote(test_actor, i , 10) for _ in range(10, 2)])`

Comment: Thank you, the mistake was in `range`, it should be `range(0, 10, 2)`. I will test this in a big dataset and see if this is a zero-copy solution.

Comment: It seems to be zero-copy even for large 2D NumPy arrays, but getting the array back or reading the array is super slow. Any idea on why is that?