# Share object between actors in Ray

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, ray

How to read and write data to the same object from multiple actors?

Docs say:
https://docs.ray.io/en/master/memory-management.html

```
import numpy as np
a = ray.put(np.zeros(1))
b = ray.get(a)
```

but this makes new copy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right way to use global variables among actors (that you can read/write) is to use an actor that holds an object. https://docs.google.com/document/d/167rnnDFIVRhHhK4mznEIemOtj63IOhtIPvSYaPgI4Fg/edit#heading=h.eg7m6lz2y48u

Plasma objects are immutable, and you can only modify the object after you copy them to worker's heap memory (meaning it is not global anymore at that point).

Also note that for your example, it doesn't create a new copy! It uses something called zero-copy read (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0574/), meaning only the in-band data (metadata for numpy object) is copied, and the out of band data (buffer) is not copied to your python's heap memory (it resides in the shared memory, and your ray program directly pointes to that memory region).

Comment: This worked!  Excellent answer. Thank You.

Comment: Although, this solution does seem to cause this error:
https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/8003